# I am trying to make a method for standard deviation but when I run the test it times out

Tags: java

This is my code and when I run a test it times out.

```
public  static  double standardDeviation(int[] numbers) {
    double jo = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        jo+=numbers[i];
    jo=jo/numbers.length;
    double[] joArray = new double[numbers.length];
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    {
        joArray[i]=Math.pow(numbers[i]-jo,2.0);
    }
    double jo2=0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<joArray.length; i++)
        jo2+=joArray[i];
    jo2=Math.sqrt(jo2/joArray.length);
    return jo2;
}
```

For those that want to see the test:

```
public void testStdDev0()
{
   assertEquals(0.8165, MiscCollectionOfFunMethodsI.standardDeviation(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }),    0.01);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger or adding some prints to see how far it gets?

Comment: @John3136 I tried the debugger and I think I see my problem thanks!

Comment: java protip: the "for each" version of the for loop would make this code much easier to read: `for(int v: numbers) { jo += v; }`, `for(double v: joArray) { jo2 += v; }`

Comment: I'm not observing the timeout behavior.  I actually see the test passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the for loops are clear and precise.

Also you want to make sure that the code has no loops.

If you clean if up it shouldn't time out.

```
public  static  double standardDeviation(int[] numbers) {
    double jo = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        jo+=numbers[i];
    jo=jo/numbers.length;
    double[] joArray = new double[numbers.length];
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    {
        joArray[i]=Math.pow(numbers[i]-jo,2.0);
    }
    double jo2=0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<joArray.length; i++)
        jo2+=joArray[i];
    jo2=Math.sqrt(jo2/joArray.length);
    return jo2;
}


public  static  double average(int[] numbers) {
    double jo = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        jo+=numbers[i];
    return jo/numbers.length;
}
```